# R: Make new column that summarizes boolean values

Tags: r

I have a table with several columns containing TRUE and FALSE values. For example:

```
Table <- data.frame("A" = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), "B" = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), "C" = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

To get the summary of each column I can use:

```
summary(Table)
```

To get:

```
     A               B               C          
 Mode :logical   Mode :logical   Mode :logical  
 FALSE:2         FALSE:3         FALSE:1        
 TRUE :3         TRUE :2         TRUE :4        
 NA's :0         NA's :0         NA's :0
```

However, I would like to print this as a single vector of percent TRUE. For example

```
     A               B               C          
 60%   60%   80%
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest solution is:

```
colMeans(Table)

##   A   B   C 
## 0.6 0.4 0.8
```

Answer (score 2):

You could of course format the output further. But essentially this would do the trick:

```
> apply(Table,2,function(c) sum(c)/length(c))
  A   B   C 
0.6 0.4 0.8
```

Comment: Yes, or more simply, `colMeans(Table)`.

Comment: yes ... :) but this way he learns something about apply() ... I don't give fish - I teach fishing, you know